# JavaScript key/value pair unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript

I am creating an array of key/value pairs inside of a function. This function will then later be called.
Code in the function:

```
function getChosenList()
  {
    var selectedList = document.getElementById("selList");
    var selectedListLength = selectedList.options.length;
    var list=[];
    if(selectedListLength>0)
      {
        for(var i=0;i<selectedListLength;i++)
          {
            var key = selectedList.options[i].value;
            var value = selectedList.options[i].text;
            list.push({key:key,value:value});
          }
        console.log(list);

      }
    return list;
  }
```

The output to the console looks like this:

```
[>object  >object  >object]
```

When the objects are expanded, it looks like this:

```
[v object            v object            v object]
    key: "1"            key: "2"            key: "3"
    value: "val_1"      value: "val_2"      value: "val_3"
```

Then I call this function from another script in the same file:

```
var listOfChosenItems = getChosenList();
console.log(listOfChosenItems);
```

This gives an output to the log that looks like this:

```
[>object  >object  >object]
```

When the objects are expanded, it looks like this:

```
[v object            v object            v object]
    key: "1"            key: "2"            key: "3"
    value: "[object]"   value: "[object]"   value: "[object]"
```

Does anyone have a clue why it's doing this? And of course a solution?

Comment: Try to replicate in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/)

Comment: getChosenList() transforms your objects. Try to show us this function.

Comment: I'm showing you the entire getChosenList() function, it's the one the original console.log is in. And then I'm literally just calling getChosenList() from the other function and immediately logging it.

Comment: What's the [object] actual content? Could you console.log(value) before the push(), to see what's in there?

Comment: When I console.log(value) I get the value I want, for instance "val_1", however it does not have "", so I take it it's not a string. This is weird because when I .push() it and console.log it, it appears between "". I can't just force value into becoming a string because this function has to be generic, so sometimes it will be strings, other times it will be integers, and so on.

Comment: Well, I did a typeof() on value, it shows that it is a String, so that just confuses me more.